# How to avoid APM field explosion exceeding 1024 fields?

Tags: node.js, elk, apm

We are using ELK APM from NodeJS running in Azure App Service. We currently have APM version 1.7.16. The APM index patterns has 1467 fields, which makes search across all fields fail with this error:

```
"type" : "query_shard_exception",
"reason" : "failed to create query: field expansion matches too many fields, limit: 1024, got: 1443",
```

This makes it very hard to use APM for free-text searching. If I search for exact matches on exact field names it works but this is less useful than free-text search.

We use NodeJS library elastic-apm-node version ^3.20.0.

I am aware of the indices.query.bool.max_clause_count setting which apparently can be set to a higher number. But I can't figure out how to do that on hosted ELK instances on elastic. It would be better if I could limit the amount of fields in the APM data in the first place. It seems to have exploded.

Does anybody know how I can fix it, so that free-text search from the Discover pane or from the APM pane starts working again?